# How to have a function do nothing without defining it?

Tags: python

I want to have some functions that are called whenever a method of my object is called. These functions aren't defined by the method - they are given to the method later on (or may not be given at all). Is there a more elegant placeholder solution than using:

```py
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bind = self.donothing #variable that may or may not be set by the parent

    def func(self):
        """Function to be called by the parent"""
        self.bind()

        ## do stuff

    @staticmethod
    def donothing():
        pass
```

Comment: I think you are looking for decorators. Read about them

Comment: What's the actual use case? If you wanted to define a getattr call that defaults to your do-nothing that's an option, but it's hard to tell what the problem you're trying to solve is, and thus which solutions might be appropriate.

Comment: What's wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question a while ago not knowing the answer. I have since learnt that the answer would be:

```py
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bind = lambda *a, **b: ()

    def func(self):
        """Function to be called by the parent"""
        self.bind()

        ## do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bind = None

    def func(self):
        """Function to be called by the parent"""
        if self.bind:
            self.bind()

            ## do stuff

    def define_function(self, f):
        self.bind = f
```

Functions, like other objects, can be used as parameters to methods. Just initialize your variable without a value and assign one to it using a setter.